# Sharepoint Environment setup

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, windows-server-2008

If I have Domain Environment,there is Domain controller and Rights management server (RMS is for documents security .. that means that u can put permissions for some users to copy , print , edit ...etc depending on their permissions.)
this RMS must integrate with SQL server as its data base .. and need sharepoint server
now users will connect to sharepoint , and sharepoint will give them their permissions which were given on RMS server
I need to know the requirements to setup that sharepoint and SQL server , 
and i need to know if the SQL & sharepoint is a separated downloadable products or they are Roles included with Windows server 2008

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server and Sharepoint Server are not Windows roles, they are separate products entirely.